# How to use Sar and kSar

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring, sar

How do I use sar to generate monitoring files on a remote server that I can then copy to my local and graph with the kSar tool?

(My server can only be accessed via the cmd)

Answer (score 1):

You have to copy the /var/log/sa/ directory from your remote server to the local machine. If the local machine and remote systems are different in OS versions, then sar might give unpredictable results. Be sure to use the same binary of sar through out the systems from where you are copying and where you are keeping the sar data to examine.

After you have got the sar files, just load them up on ksar and be done.

This is in a nutshell, if you have specific requirements, I might have precise answers.

Answer (score 0):

Sar's data files are stored in /var/log/sa/sa?? , named for the day of the month.  Note this assumes a Red Hat style distro; files might be elsewhere on Debian/Ubuntu.